# iDangerous Swiper, how to scroll to the correct image when click in thumbnail?

Tags: swiper.js

I have a swiper instance that has DIVs in the main carousel and images in the pager carousel.

I click on one of the thmumbnails in the pager, I want it should scroll to the correct image in the main carousel.
How to do it, ty

Comment: You should attempt to resolve this problem and then when you have a specific problem with some part of making it work, post a question here.

Answer (score -1):

Swiper v.3.1.0 will have a

```
paginationBulletRender(index, className)
```

parameter, you can use this here.